# Convert DateTime format to MMMM yyyy, dd using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to change the date format to MM:yyyy:dd (October 2018, 24), I've tried every method I know, but it's not working... here is my code(one of many method I got online):

```
var data = (from o in db.tbPATxns
                            join p in db.providers on o.providerid equals p.providertin
                            join a in db.Endorsements on o.panumber equals a.panumber
                            join b in db.members on o.IID equals b.legacycode
                            join c in db.proceduredatas on a.proccode equals c.procedurecode
                            where c.proceduredesc.ToLower().Contains("admission")
                            select new
                            {
                                o.panumber,
                                b.legacycode,
                                b.lastname,
                                b.firstname,
                                b.phone1,
                                p.providername,
                                a.txndate.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")
                            });

                RadGrid1.DataSource = data.ToList();
                RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

that query is suppose to get all the required field from the database, so what I want is to convert that datetime from database to (MMMM yyyy, dd), but the `toString` is returning 2 type of errors.

(1)

> No Overload For Method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

(2)

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declare with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

If I remove the `ToString`, the output will be

```
6/21/2018 4:40:15 PM
```

Comment: @Tim txndate is a datetime, if I remove the toString, the output will be 6/21/2018 4:40:15 PM

Comment: Maybe it's a nullable DateTime?! Then you have to use `a.txndate==null ? "" : a.txndate.Value.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to fetch your records as it is by `AsEnumerable` and then apply date formatting on projected records like

```
select new
{
   o.panumber,
   b.legacycode,
   b.lastname,
   b.firstname,
   b.phone1,
   p.providername,
   a.txndate       //as it is
})
.AsEnumerable()
// now convert
.Select(a => new
{
   panumber = a.panumber,
   legacycode = a.legacycode,
   lastname = a.lastname,
   firstname = a.firstname,
   phone1 = a.phone1,
   providername = a.providername,
   txndate = a.txndate.Value.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")
});
```

Comment: You're a Genius, I got Exactly what I wanted.... Thanks alot, I really appreaciate

Comment: can I ask you one more question please?

Comment: what if am using a query like this**SELECT * FROM member_case_management**..... datetime is among the data to be selected, how do I convert it? I hope you don't mind, Thanks

Comment: If you used sql query with `ado.net` then you can format it while you read your reader like => `while (reader.Read())
            {
                string formattedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["txndate"])?.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd");
            }`

Comment: please I don't understand, this is my full code 

`DataTable dt = new DataTable();



            SQLDataManager sql = new SQLDataManager(false);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM member_case_management where panumber like '%'+ @value +'%'";



            sql.AddParamAndValue("@value", searchvalue);


            dt = sql.GetDataset(query, CommandType.Text).Tables[0];

            return dt;`

Comment: string query = "SELECT * FROM member_case_management where panumber like '%'+ @value +'%'";

Comment: you can do this after `dt = sql.GetDataset` call => `var response = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            select new
                            {
                                //...
                                a = r.Field<string>("a"),
                                b = r.Field<DateTime>("b").ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")
                                //---
                            }).ToList();`

Comment: and assign proper return type to method

Comment: my grid is empty, not displaying any data

Comment: proper return type like, please am totally new to c#

Comment: could you please ask a new question with all the details so it will be better to resolve your problem ASAP bcoz another user may get confused if he/she following this question and after posting question you may post link to comments below or any talented guy will help you :)

Comment: I've ask a new question as you instructed sir

Comment: I leaved my office, I'll try to give you a solution tomorrow, if anyone's answer help you then you can proceed :)

Comment: no answer is helping sir, I will wait for you tomorrow sir. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You probably intend to use the ToString() method (notice capital T).
Also, if your txndate is nullable, add the null conditional operator:

```
var data = (from o in db.tbPATxns
                        join p in db.providers on o.providerid equals p.providertin
                        join a in db.Endorsements on o.panumber equals a.panumber
                        join b in db.members on o.IID equals b.legacycode
                        join c in db.proceduredatas on a.proccode equals c.procedurecode
                        where c.proceduredesc.ToLower().Contains("admission")
                        select new
                        {
                            o.panumber,
                            b.legacycode,
                            b.lastname,
                            b.firstname,
                            b.phone1,
                            p.providername,
                            a.txndate?.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")
                        });
```

Comment: _" (1) No Overload For Method 'toString' takes 1 arguments"_

Comment: Because the method name is ToString (capital 'T'), as I said.

Comment: this is the error am having with your method **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Comment: What type is a.txndate? If nullable DateTime, change to a.txndate?.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")

Comment: its not showing any data on my grid, remember am binding the output to a grid

Answer (score 0):

The first error suggest that `a.txndate` is not a `DateTime`. Perhaps it's a `Nullable<DateTime>` as Tim suggested. The second error message means you must provide a name for that property since the c# compiler will not infer it from the value - so Assuming a `Nullable<DateTime>` you can probably do something like this (the query omitted since it's irrelevant to the errors):

```
select new
{
    o.panumber,
    b.legacycode,
    b.lastname,
    b.firstname,
    b.phone1,
    p.providername,
    txndate = a.txndate == null ? "" : a.txndate.Value.ToString("MMMM yyyy, dd")
}
```

Comment: the fact is that if I use this method, it will not display anything in the grid, the cell collecting the date will be empty

Comment: Try to change txnDate to txndate.

Comment: @kaffekopp force of habit... I didn't even noticed that capital :-) good catch!